# SharePoint Online List Accordion

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I am needing to create an accordion in SharePoint web part for online, however I am quiet new to JS & Jquery.

Is there an example of an accordion that I can use to help this?

The items must be referencing the SP list & items inside.

A little guidance will be grateful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI accordion and get the items using REST API as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
GetItems();
});
function GetItems(){
var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Loyalty%20Rewards')/items",   //change the list name
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
        success: function(data) {
         if (data.d.results.length > 0) 
           {
            $('#accordion').append(GenerateAccordionFromJson(data.d.results));  
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
           }
         else{  
            $('#accordion').append("<span>No Records Found.</span>");  
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }  
    });
}  
function GenerateAccordionFromJson(objArray) 
    {  
    var accordionContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) 
    {  
        accordionContent += '<h3>' + objArray[i].Title + '</h3>';               
               //change the column name
        accordionContent += '<div><p>' + objArray[i].Description + '</p></div>';           //change the column name
    }
    return accordionContent;
    }


</script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is tested and works well, all you need to is change the list title and the column name from where you want to show the data.

Reference: [jQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Thanks! But how would the items inside the accordion be referenced from the SP list? As this needs to display the information

Comment: I have changed the code that binds the list data (using REST API) dynamically in accordion.

Comment: Hi I have tried to use your code and updated the list name and column name but i got an error when loading this on the page

Comment: Please tell me what error you get so that I can help you further.

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, System.ArgumentException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"List 'Upcoming COPs' does not exist at site with URL 'https://bp365.sharepoint.com'.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List 'Upcoming COPs' does not exist at site with URL 'https://bp365.sharepoint.com'."}}},"status":404,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: The list and page will be stored in a site collection in a subsite.

Comment: Your code is referring to root site and your list is present in subsite. 
So I have updated the URL in the code.

_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl gets the url of your current web

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and this is the error i get {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, System.ArgumentException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"List 'Upcoming COPs' does not exist at site with URL 'https://bp365.sharepoint.com'.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List 'Upcoming COPs' does not exist at site with URL 'https://bp365.sharepoint.com'."}}},"status":404,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: You might be referring an incorrect name of list in the REST URL.

Comment: @DanielleSutton Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you :)

Comment: @sohali shaikh this is the code i used:                                                                      <html>
<head>

<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @DanielleSutton I think you exceed the characters limit and so i'm not able to see your full code accept the jQuery references.

Comment: I have placed it into a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EtmLPHdt2h

Comment: @DanielleSutton the code is same as mine

Comment: Hi Sohail, I have updated the list name and fields inside the list that is correct? What else would need to change for this to work?

Comment: @DanielleSutton I hope the online references of jQuery and jQuery UI is not blocked for your intranet application.

Comment: do you use google hangouts to talk about this further?

Comment: I have just tested the online references and to those sites and they connect correctly to display the scripts

Comment: @DanielleSutton Sure
hmu at sohailshaikh1295@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show list items as accordion in list view, we can use JSLINK to achieve it. The following code for your reference. Create a custom list and add "Description" column into this list, then add the code below into a script editor web part in list view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 

    // jQuery library is required in this sample 
    // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var accordionContext = {}; 
    accordionContext.Templates = {}; 

    // Be careful when add the header for the template, because it's will break the default list view render 
    accordionContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='accordion'>"; 
    accordionContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>"; 

    // Add OnPostRender event handler to add accordion click events and style 
    accordionContext.OnPostRender = accordionOnPostRender; 

    // This line of code tell TemplateManager that we want to change all HTML for item row render 
    accordionContext.Templates.Item = accordionTemplate; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(accordionContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function accordionTemplate(ctx) { 
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"]; 
    var description = ctx.CurrentItem["Description"]; 

    // Return whole item html 
    return "<h2>" + title + "</h2><div>" + description + "</div><br/>"; 
} 

function accordionOnPostRender() { 

    // Register event to collapse and uncollapse when click on accordion header 
    $('.accordion h2').click(function () { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
    }).next().hide(); 

    $('.accordion h2').css('cursor', 'pointer'); 
}
</script>
```

If you want to build accordion base on the list items in a client web part, we need using REST API to get the list data and build the accordion using jQuery.

Comment: HI I have tried to add your JS file. I updated the fields, uploaded the file to site assets library, added the list to the page and referanced the file and this still hasnt worked. I didnt see anything change within the list.

Comment: Did you try to add the code into a script editor web part in list view.

Comment: As in the miscellaneous part of the list webpart under the JS link? This is where i was referencing the script. Or are you speaking about a different way to load the script editor into the list? Is this in the list itself?

Comment: @LZ_MSFT , using the Sohail's solution, how to create the sections --   say am having a "category1" section as a first title of accordion  with column1, column2 of splist are listed and then category2 as second section title under which column3, column4 of splist are listed

Comment: @sohail - how to create a  category if the names are different - say, i have  a  category called Admin --its a  section name --with column3, column4 ,column5 are present.  section names are just labels and not columns/fields of the splist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've explored a more OOB option, but possibly using the 'Group By' setting in a new view would work? This styling option for a view allows for an collapsible accordion feature; however, you must choose a column upon which the items are grouped (which ends up being displayed as the heading for each group).

[image]

Cheers

Comment: There's a difference between accordion and group by. 
Accordion displays content of only one category at a time.
Group by can display contents of various category at a time.

Comment: Sure but I don't think that means it couldn't be a viable solution for what Danielle is looking to accomplish, based on how she described it.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this option for an FAQ list and it worked like magic.  The key is to create the JS file and then when you add the webpart to a new page add the link in the JSlink of the webpart.

```
(function () {

    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};

    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='ListAccordion'>";
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = OnPostRender;
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Item = ItemTemplate;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);

})();



function ItemTemplate(ctx) {
    var Question  = ctx.CurrentItem["Question"];
    var Answer = ctx.CurrentItem["Answer"];

    return "<h2>" + Question + "</h2><p>" + Answer + "</p><br/>";
    }

function OnPostRender() {

    $('.ListAccordion h2').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).next().hide();

    $('.ListAccordion h2').css({
    "background-color": "grey", 
    "cursor": "pointer", 
    "color": "white" ,
    "border-radius" : "15px",
    "padding-left" : "10px"
    });
}
```

I got the instructions from this link  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-accordion-in-sharepoint-using-js-link-and-client-side-rendering/

Hope this gets you closer